# jquery if siblings hasClass

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery which checks a form on submission:

```
$('#register_button').click(function (e) {
    var valid = true;
    $('.controls input').each(function () {
        if ($(this).siblings().hasClass('error')) {
            valid = false;
            alert('errors!');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my HTML structure for an input:

```
<div class="controls">
    <input type="text" name="register_postcode" id="register_postcode" value="<?=(isset($_REQUEST['register_postcode']) ? $_REQUEST['register_postcode'] : 'xxxxxx')?>" />                    
    <div class="info">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="valid" style="display:none;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="error" style="display:none;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

When submitting the form and there are errors the alert shows.

But when I submit the form and there are no errors, the alert still shows and the form isnt submitted.

Any ideas?

Comment: i don't think that is your full HTML code.. is it ??

Comment: no as mentioned above its for an input. pointless posting all input when they are all pretty much the same

Comment: Unless you **remove** the `div` with class `error` (or remove the class), the input element will **always** have a sibling with class `error`. The visibility of the `div` element has no influence on this.

Comment: because the sibling still has the calss error but not visible

Comment: test for `if($(this).siblings('.error:visible').length`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From what I can see if the input element is valid, you are not removing the element with class `error`, it is just hidden.

So change your test from being checking whether there is a sibling with class `error` to whether the `error` is visible

```
$('#register_button').click(function (e) {
    var valid = true;
    $('.controls input').each(function () {
        if ($(this).siblings('.error:visible').length) {
            valid = false;
            alert('errors!');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

You can also do

```
$('#register_button').click(function (e) {
    if($('.controls .error:visible').length){
        alert('errors!');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```